# Reflection GetField() not working from GetType(), only typeof(T)

Tags: c#, reflection, aot

I'm running into some odd behavior with reflection.  It seems like a bug.
I've been using reflection in my c# project to access public fields in my various custom data types.  I've been using mono to run my code on a Mac but for the first time, I built a native stand-alone project using "dotnet publish -r osx-x64 -c Release --self-contained -p:PublishAot=true".  Everything works correctly except GetField/GetFields.

A class in my project has a public string called *name*, for example.  Let's say that class is called *being*.

```
//o is of type object which is an instance of being
o.GetType().GetField("name").SetValue(o, "somevalue");
```

The line above crashes with an object reference not set to an instance of an object because GetField("name") returns null.  Similarly, GetFields() returns an empty array even though I have dozens of public fields in being.

The reason this seems like a bug to me is, it will work if I access being in this manner first:

```
var field = typeof(being).GetField("name");
```

I don't even have to DO anything with *field*.  Simply calling GetField() on typeof(being) will make the GetType() from my instance suddenly start returning fields.  HUH?  How is this possible since the line above is not even involved?
I need a workaround regardless of whether it's a bug or not.  In some cases, I don't know the type at compile time so I can't do typeof(being), typeof(monster), etc.  I have to rely on GetType().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you notice this behavior only when running the application from `dotnet publish` (and the Release profile)? If so, try without PublishAot, as that performs trimming. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows#limitations-of-native-aot-deployment

Comment: A huge switch statement with all of my types would work too but it looks like I have to go without PublishAot as you said beccause I ran into an additional problem.  Marshalling isn't supported and I use it to call native code I built in C++.  I think I give up on Aot.  To answer the question, the behavior doesn't happen with dotnet publish (no AOT) but I was trying to get a performance boost.

Comment: Unrelated: the need to resort to reflection raises a red flag. If you don't know the type at compile time, maybe you are not using an interface where you should have?

Comment: I'm sorry, I phrased that wrong.  I expect a certain type but, unless I have a switch statement to handle all types, I can't loop through the fields like I used to by using GetType().  Now I have to verbosely specify each type in the code.